# Probability of choosing $1$ out of $4$ guesses correctly

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Suppose a machine generates $4$ numbers picked at random from $1$ to $20$.
All sequences are possible.

Now I choose $4$ numbers as well. What is the chance that one of my numbers is similar to one of the machine choices.

Example: machine choose $1,9,13,11$

I chose $7,4,2,9 $

This is good because we both chose $9$.

Another example: $2,2,2,2$
I chose $4,2,2,5$

Good. Because we both chose $2$. (Even though it doesn't make sense that u chose $2$ twice. Suppose all $4$ are picked at random.)

I prefer to do it using simple math instead of combinatorics of sequences.
I did something like $(\frac{1}{20})\cdot4$ for first number. Then add  $(\frac{1}{19})\cdot3$  etc.
Am I wrong? It looks like it is close but still wrong possibly I should calculate the chances of no numbers are in common? But I cant see how.

Should it be $1-4 (\frac{19}{20})^4$?

Comment: It is much simpler if you insist that each set of choices have four different numbers.  Then you can just compute the chance that none of your numbers match any of the computer's.  If you don't I think you should first compute the chance that a set of numbers has $1,2,3,4$ distinct numbers, then compute the chance of no match given the number of distinct numbers in each set.

Comment: If both are choosing four distinct numbers then the probability of exactly one match is $\frac{{4 \choose 1}{16 \choose 3}}{20 \choose 4} =\frac{448}{969} \approx 0.4623$, while the probability of at least one match is $1-\frac{{4 \choose 0}{16 \choose 4}}{20 \choose 4}= \frac{605}{969} \approx 0.6244$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you choose $4$ different numbers, you might as well choose $1, 2, 3, 4$ to be your numbers.  The question then becomes what fraction of sequences *don’t* use any of the first $4$ numbers.  Subtract that fraction from $1$ and you have your answer.

There are $16^4$ sequences that don’t use the first $4$ numbers and there are $20^4$ possible sequences.  The probability of a complete miss is therefore $\left (\dfrac 45\right )^4=0.4096$, so the probability of a hit is exactly $1-0.4096=0.5904$.

Your proposed solution doesn’t work because it fails to account for the possibility that your first number ends up matching the second, third, or fourth number in the sequence

Comment: Nice answer thanks

Comment: Only that your answer works for "at least" one common number.  Not for "exactly" one common number

Comment: @bilanush in your example: machine 2,2,2,2 and you chose 4,2,2,5: that could be seen as eight matches.  Are both you and the machine choosing at random?  Are you ignoring duplicates of the same number?

Comment: @Henry Yes its the same number 2.  So I call it one number. But can't be a match of say 1265 vs 1287. Because 2 number match now

Comment: @Henry I don't refer to them as matches . But rather as guesses. One number guessed correctly.  Duplicates are irrelevant in my game

Answer (score 1):

The answer and the ease of calculation depends on the precise rules for selecting numbers.

Simulation of the number of duplicates will get you a close answer quickly and allow you consider the different ways the numbers might be picked.

For example, using R:

```
dupes <- function(tot, n, replacen, k, replacek){
  x <- unique(sample(1:tot, n, replace=replacen))
  y <- unique(sample(1:tot, k, replace=replacek))
  return(sum(y %in% x))
  }
set.seed(2023)
cases <- 10^6
```

when **both choose numbers without replacement**, this gives the approximate probability for at least one duplicate of approximately $0.625$, $1-\frac{{4 \choose 0}{16 \choose 4}}{20 \choose 4}= \frac{605}{969} \approx 0.6244$ theoretically, and exactly one duplicate of approximately $0.463$, $\frac{{4 \choose 1}{16 \choose 3}}{20 \choose 4} =\frac{448}{969} \approx 0.4623$ theoretically:

```
table(replicate(cases, dupes(20, 4, FALSE, 4, FALSE)))/cases

       0        1        2        3        4 
0.375303 0.462582 0.148733 0.013182 0.000200
```

and when **one chooses numbers without replacement and the other chooses with replacement**, gives the approximate probability for at least one duplicate of approximately $0.590$, $1-\left(\frac{16}{20}\right)^5=\frac{369}{625} = 0.5904$ theoretically as in Robert Shore's calculation, and exactly one duplicate of approximately $0.449$:

```
table(replicate(cases, dupes(20, 4, TRUE,  4, FALSE)))/cases

       0        1        2        3        4 
0.409789 0.449242 0.130356 0.010484 0.000129
```

and when **both choose numbers with replacement** gives the approximate probability for at least one duplicate of approximately $0.577$, and exactly one duplicate of approximately $0.435$:

```
table(replicate(cases, dupes(20, 4, TRUE,  4, TRUE )))/cases

       0        1        2        3        4 
0.442739 0.435119 0.113820 0.008218 0.000104
```

Comment: Sorry the answer wasn't clear to me. I am talking about machin and human picking 4 numbers at random from 1 to 20. Duplicates are allowed.   Then the question is probability that they have one number in common.  According to the examples I gave. 4566 vs 6666 is a match.  But 4566 vs 5566 is not a match  because 2 numbers are in common.  To what category of your answer does this belong? Thanks

Comment: @bilanush For both "machine and human picking 4 numbers at random from 1 to 20" with replacement, the bottom table gives the simulated probabilities of $0,1,2,3,4$ matches. This covers your duplicates. One of these you can easily check theoretically: the probability for $4$ matches should be $\frac{8721}{80000000} \approx 0.000109$ so the simulated $0.000104$ was close.   The middle table gives the simulated probabilities for when the machine picks 4 numbers at random from 1 to 20 with replacement and the human aims to maximise the expected number of matches (by choosing without replacement).

Comment: I don't understand your answer. But thanks